# Unable to install openblas-devel on Redhat 7

Tags: redhat, yum

I tried command below

```
yum install openblas-devel
```

but the package is not avaialble in using Yum

My Yum.conf is like below

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=3

[comments abridged]

# PUT YOUR REPOS HERE OR IN separate files named file.repo
# in /etc/yum.repos.d
```

tried solution provided below but still did not work

```
[root@server ec2-user]# subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-*-optional-rpms \
>                            --enable rhel-*-extras-rpms \
>                            --enable rhel-ha-for-rhel-*-server-rpms
Repositories disabled by configuration.

WARNING

The yum/dnf plugins: /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/subscription-manager.conf were automatically enabled for the benefit of Red Hat Subscription Management. If not desired, use "subscription-manager config --rhsm.auto_enable_yum_plugins=0" to block this behavior.

[root@server ec2-user]# yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, product-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm                                                                                             |  15 kB  00:00:00     
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-QKKmT8/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm: epel-release-7-14.noarch
/var/tmp/yum-root-QKKmT8/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@server ec2-user]#
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable EPEL repo, the package is located [there](https://rhel.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/openblas-devel-0.3.3-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html).

As described [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/#_el7) you can enable it with command:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-*-optional-rpms \
                           --enable rhel-*-extras-rpms \
                           --enable rhel-ha-for-rhel-*-server-rpms
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: any idea how to enable it? I am new in this

Comment: I tried this but still did not work. udpated my question

Comment: @ZachFara, register your server in RHEL